# Linq to Entity - Join Update

Tags: linq, entity-framework

This might be easy for you guys but am stuck to convert into linq. 
here is my sql query

```
update Sevt set
 UserFlag4 = 0
from Sevt, Wo W
where Sevt.Seqnum = W.SeqNum and w.WONUM = '1502411'
```

Here is two table joined but not sure how to convert in to LINQ. Any help much appreciated, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Linq is for querying only. In itself it has nothing to do with Databases either. So this question makes no sense...Further more with nHibernate/Linq2SQL/EF you can't do updates using a where clause...not directly...

Comment: @Aron, my bad, i was trying to convert my sql query to Linq to Entity.

Comment: If however the question is about Entity Framework...[Entity Framework Extensions](http://efe.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select from both tables as you would in SQL. Then update the flag and save changes.

```
var query = from s in context.Sevt
            from w in context.Wo
            where s.Seqnum == w.SeqNum && w.WONUM == "1502411"
            select s;
foreach (var set in query)
{
    set.UserFlag4 = 0;
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: for large updates this is highly unperformant. I thought that was your issue...EFE is better for large updates.